# После установки обновлений на Windows-10 отключился вай-фай

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-10, wifi

Добрый день.

Введение в проблему:

Есть ноутбук ACER Pentium четырехъядерный довольно новый (CPU N3540 покупал два года назад). На нем стояла Windows-8 после покупки она проапгрейдилась до Windows-10-64 Home Edition. Что важно для сюжета, в сеть я выхожу по вай-фаю. Windows-10-64 периодически качает обновления. Сегодня, 25.12.2017 поставилось очередное обновление. Теперь система показывает версию Windows 10 Version 1709 и номер сборки 16299.125.

Но не все оказалось так уж хорошо. После установки этого последнего обновления проявилась неприятная особенность: вай-фай отрубился напрочь, хотя роутер исправен (с этим же роутером я связывался по вай-фаю через телефон для проверки его работы и оказалось что все работает).

Причем, что интересно, вай-фай рапортует, что все нормально. То есть ноутбук видит сеть моего роутера, нормально принимает пароль и бодро рапортует, что подключение произошло. Однако, при попытке запустить браузер и выйти в сеть, браузер пишет, что подключения нет. Так же почтовый клиент на ноутбуке (у меня стоит Thunderbird) не может связаться с сервером.

Антивирусов у меня нет, кроме системного антивируса Windows 10. Галочку быстрого запуска в настройках электропитания я снял.

Вопросы:

1. Что делать? Как починить вай-фай?.

Спасибо

UPD1:

Скачал и поставил драйвера с сайта ACER - не помогло.

Comment: *ноутбук видит сеть моего роутера, нормально принимает пароль и бодро рапортует, что подключение произошло.* Что показывает при этом `IPCONFIG /ALL`? Как настроено сетевое подключение - DHCP?

Comment: Сейчас погляжу насчет IPCONFIG /ALL. Но главное дело что ничего не изменялось. Вчера все работало, и никакой IPCONFIG не надо было смотреть. А сегодня поставилось обновление и вай-фай отключился. :-( Прямо наказание какое-то, хоть запрещай обновления ставить.

Comment: Во-первых, какого хрена включено всё подряд, даже неиспользуемое? IPv6 пользуешь? нет? отключить... проводной интерфейс? отключить... блюпуп? отключить... ну и из вопроса убрать за ненадобностью. Во-вторых, тупо шлюз (192,168,0,1) - пингается? а внешний интерфейс (WAN-адрес) рутера? а его шлюз? а вообще tracert 8.8.8.8 что показывает? пустые хопы - убрать, есссно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался. Во время установки обновления ребята из Микрософт почему-то включили прокси-сервер 127.0.0.1:49781. Когда я выключил этот прокси, то все заработало. :-/

Да, спасибо за наводку. Пинг работал и при включенном прокси, а браузер не работал.

Comment: Это могли быть не ребята из MS, а что-то,  что слушало у вас HTTP трафик,  и что не успело за собой замести следы.  Так бывает, например,  с fiddler,  когда его процесс умирает.